# Why is chomp not removing whitespace around my string?

Tags: perl

I don't understand why perl `chomp` isn't removing the whitespace surrounding my string. I've even tried to call chomp twice, for example, using bash:

```
$ perl -e 'use 5.22.4; chomp(my $extra=" lol "); chomp($extra); say "<$extra>"'
< lol >
```

I really expected to get

```
<lol>
```

Comment: Why do you expect that? Please read the docs for that function.

Comment: Try looking here to trim whitespaces: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=522531

Comment: *Why is chomp not removing whitespace around my string?* Because that's not what `chomp()` does :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chomp only removes the *line ending* (can be set with `$/` variable) from the end of the string. It does not trim the string. Perl does not have a built-in trim function. I usually spell out two substitutions instead:

```
s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for $string;
```

Further reading:

- [`perldoc -f chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)
- [Perl FAQ: How do I strip blank space from the beginning/end of a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-strip-blank-space-from-the-beginning/end-of-a-string%3F)

Comment: global switch might be more useful here "$extra=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g"

Comment: [implemented in perl5i](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl5i/lib/perl5ifaq.pod#How-do-I-strip-whitespace-off-a-string?)

Answer (score 4):

To remove all whitespace:

```
$string =~ s/\s+//g;
```

Left trim:

```
$string =~ s/^\s+//;
```

Right Trim:

```
$string =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Left and Right trim:

```
$string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g
```

We can then also build trimming fucntions. This helps in much bigger scripts where you would not want to write the full replacement strings each time, we write them once, then use the function to do the work.

This simple function can be used in any script as `trim($string);`

```
sub trim {
    $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
 }
```

Similarly with a full strip of whitespace.

```
 sub full_strip {
    $_[0] =~ s/\s+//g;
 }
```

in a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "  this is line with leading and trailing whitespaces  ";
my $string2 = "         another one of those lines ";

trim($string);
trim($string2);

print "$string\n";
print "$string2\n";

full_strip($string);
full_strip($string2);

print "$string\n";
print "$string2\n";


sub trim {
    $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
   }

sub full_strip {
    $_[0] =~ s/\s+//g;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

This would work well for any generic string where you want to remove beginning and ending spaces.